Why alerts are not working in specific pine script code
//@function Draws pivot lines and labels from startTime to the approximate end of the period.
drawNewPivots(startTime) =>
newGraphics = array.new<pivotGraphic>()

for [index, coord] in pivotPointsArray
    levelSettings = graphicSettingsArray.get(index)
    if not na(coord) and levelSettings.showLevel
        lineEndTime = startTime + timeframe.in_seconds(pivotTimeframe) * 1000 * pivotYearMultiplier
        pivotLine = line.new(startTime, coord, lineEndTime, coord, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color=levelSettings.levelColor, width=linewidthInput)
        pivotLabel = label.new(x = positionLabelsInput == "Left" ? startTime : lineEndTime,
                           y = coord,
                           text = (showLabelsInput ? levelSettings.levelName + " " : "") + (showPricesInput ? "(" + str.tostring(coord, format.mintick) + ")" : ""),
                           style = positionLabelsInput == "Left" ? label.style_label_right : label.style_label_left,
                           textcolor = levelSettings.levelColor,
                           color = #00000000,
                           xloc=xloc.bar_time)
        
        newGraphics.push(pivotGraphic.new(pivotLine, pivotLabel))
        // Alert for R1 or S1 level only when price crosses
    //if (levelSettings.levelName == "R1" or levelSettings.levelName == "S1")
        if close > line.get_y1(pivotLine)
            alert("Candle closed above " + levelSettings.levelName + " (" + str.tostring(coord) + ")", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
            if close < line.get_y1(pivotLine)
                alert("Candle closed below " + levelSettings.levelName + " (" + str.tostring(coord) + ")", alert.freq_once_per_bar)


drawnGraphics.add_row(array_id = newGraphics)

Some One guide me please
